# Smallest pool to form tidal wave

Tags: water, tidal-effect

Tidal waves form in the ocean, while not in my swimming pool.

I wonder what's the smallest swimming pool is like to form tidal waves.

It's true that tidal wave always exists, let's assume we want a tidal wave with a height of 3 m.

Answer (score 0):

Larger the pool, larger the tidal effects on it.

[Tidal wave](http://www.altimetry.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/m2_amp_pha_fes99_sm.gif) from [site](http://www.altimetry.info/thematic-use-cases/ocean-applications/tides/)

Earth tized pool, tens of thousands of km has a few meters tidal wave in some areas.

Mediterranian sea, that is about 10 times shorters, thousands of km, has tens of centimeters tidal wave.

There is no strict limit after which atoms just decide 'nope, im not attracted to the moon anymore'.

But in a small pool it might be hard to measure the effect. It seems that tidal wave height has a ratio to pool length of about 1:10 000 000. So in a 10m pool you could expect tidal wave to be on the scale of 1 micron. Does it exist? Sure. Is it important? In most cases no.

Comment: if really it's the length that matters, does this mean, I can use a tiny width like 50cm but an extremely long pool to form some big tidal wave? e.g. a pool with 10k km long, 50cm wide, and 50cm in depth would form a huge tidal wave?

Comment: @yupbank you can calculate hydraulic resistance of such a channel. Take expected height difference that a big pool would make, and hydraulic resistance of this channel, to find the result. http://www.pressure-drop.com/Online-Calculator/ for your data pressure drop is about 2 meters, comparable to the gain you get from the tidal wave. so the 'pool' size would decrease to a size where hydraulic pressure drop is less than tidal wave height. Where pool is more like a sphere and less like a channel.